# TCL sage profiler

Tags: tcl

I'm looking for the TCL code called "sage" from John Stump, which profiles each procedure.
The TCL wiki shows a dead link, and I'm unable to find it elsewhere.
Until then, I'm using the TCLX "profile" command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fortunate, in that the page was archived by the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/web/). I've put a copy I've extracted from the archive on [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5nadoJDv8CNbTJmVzFGa2Y4ak0/view?usp=sharing) as a temporary solution. It could really do with putting somewhere better, but I don't have the personal bandwidth to take it on myself.

Comment: It looks like the reason the code is rotting is that the author died. It happens.

Comment: Thanks!  The Internet Archive link to sage v1.1 is here:  https://web.archive.org/web/20010430041015/http://www.geocities.com/SiliconValley/Ridge/2549/sage/

Comment: ...and I've edited the tcl wiki page with the same link

Comment: Unfortunately the 1.1 page doesn't have a valid link to the 1.1 source code.

Comment: I'm curious.  Where did you find the 1.0 source code?

Comment: It was in the IA. At least apparently. (The code is the source, of course.)

Comment: I just put the URL I had into the IA and clicked _something_ and I got the file.